# VBA Macro to sum a variable range and put the result in the specified column

Tags: vba, excel

i am summing the column (TOTAL_DLR_AM) and its working fine,i would like to know how do i put the calculated sum in the column named sum.

The below codes i am using for calculating the sum from the column (TOTAL_DLR_AM) and its working.

myrow = Range("E6666").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=SUM(E3:E" & myrow & ")"

u can check the workbook in the below link.

[image: click here]

Comment: `doesn't paste` because you didn't code it?

Comment: Your use of `FormulaR1C1` is totally wrong. You're supposed to provide it with a formula using R1C1 notation (which explains why it's named what it is), not just the word *Sum*. Get rid of your last like (`Offset().Formula`) and replace it with `FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM()"` as you have it in the line I told you to remove. When in doubt, record a macro and read the code the Macro Recorder generates to see how to use something.

Comment: @KenWhite I will bet dollars to doughnuts that the macro recorder is the one that put the line `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sum"`  It works in that it will place the word `Sum` in the cell as text.  The Question I have is WHY?  Why use a macro at all.  it is not detrimental to the calc times or output to sum empty cells simply putting `=SUM(E3:E666)` will return the same answer and just as fast as limiting the range.

Comment: `doesn't paste the calculated sum in the column (Sum).` that is because you are offsetting the column not the row.  The first number in the Offset() is the row and the second is the column, so you are moving over 4 columns and placing the formula.  I think you want to switch them.

Comment: @Scott: Probably, if the poster made a mistake recording and started typing into the cell. The recorder is usually pretty accurate, though (although somewhat verbose). I had the same question as to why, but ran out of space.